# Parsing Get HTTP Request for parameters and using in http response

Tags: node.js, http, query-string, url-parsing

I am trying to learn node.js. Here is the basic hello World example where I expect a http request like

```
http://localhost:3000?fname=ABC&lname=XYZ
```

And return response to print on the browser

```
Hello, ABC XYZ!
```

This is working fine. But if you see the `response.end` function I have something like `query.lname || "Anonymous"`. I was expecting that in case the lname is not specified in the URL then the response contains 'Anonymous' in place of last name. But this doesn't happen and I get

```
Hello, ABC undefined!
```

The code is as follows. Kindly help me understand this. Thanks for the help.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   var query = querystring.parse(url.parse(request.url).query || "");
   response.writeHead(200,{’content-type’:"text/plain"});
   response.end("Hello, "+(query.fname+" "+ query.lname || "Anonymous")+"!\n");
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Try enclosing `(query.lname || "Anonymous")` in parentheses

Comment: Also, `querystring.parse(url.parse(request.url).query || "")` can be rewritten as simply `url.parse(request.url, true).query`

Comment: Thanks that worked. But, then in current form if I don't specify both first and last name then It should give anonymous right? But that also doesn't work

Comment: @mscdex Can you elaborate on that. Sorry I am new to node. But what exactly it will do?

Comment: For that you'd want something like `(query.fname && query.lname ? query.fname + ' ' + query.lname : 'Anonymous')`

Comment: Passing `true` as a second argument to [`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) will parse the query string for you.